# How to mave a shape smoothely with arrow keys on html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, keypress, event-listener

How exactly do i make a rectangular shape move around with the arrow keys on html5 canvas? how do you actually even detect a keypress? VS Code keeps saying that event.keyCode is deprecated.
Any help is appreciated
my code so far:

```
<!doctype html><html>
<canvas></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

var vw = window.innerWidth / 100;
var vh = window.innerHeight / 100;

c.fillRect(vw * 1, vh * 97, vw * 23, vh * 3);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post the code you have so far.

Comment: A Haworth I have edited my question to include the code.

Comment: Where’s the code which is setting up the event listener for key press?

Comment: I haven't done that yet because I have no idea how to set it up to detect key presses. I am new to pregramming

Comment: You probably are looking for the keydown event, see for example [link] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event Then test to see if it’s an arrow and if so clear your canvas and redraw the rectangle in whatever new position you want.